# How to convert Hexadecimal value to byte in java

Tags: javascript, java, android, hex, byte

I have written two functions which accepts an integer converts it into hexadecimal value and returns byte value.

For example

`Scenario 1`
decimal value - 400
Hexadecimal value - 0x190
getYLHeight() should return 90
getYHHeight() should return 1

`Scenario 2`
decimal value - 124
Hexadecimal value - 0x7C
getYLHeight() should return 7C
getYHHeight() should return 0

Scenario 1 works fine as the Hexadecimal value are integers
But in scenario 2 Hexadecimal value 7C cannot be converted to int

Is there a better way to write the bellow code to work for both scenarios

```
 System.out.println("YL -" + hw.getYLHeight(400));//Hex value - 0x190,should return 90 - WORKS
 System.out.println("YH -" + hw.getYHHeight(400));//Hex value - 0x190,should return 1 - WORKS
 //System.out.println(hw.getYLHeight(124));//Hex value - 0x7C should return 7C - DOES NOT WORK
 //System.out.println(hw.getYHHeight(124));//Hex value - 0x7C should return 0 - DOES NOT WORK



  private byte getYLHeight(int height) {
            int hexNewImageBytesLength = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(height));
            byte yl = (byte)(hexNewImageBytesLength % 100);
            return yl;
        }

             private byte getYHHeight(int height) {
            int hexNewImageBytesLength = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(height));
            byte yh = (byte)(hexNewImageBytesLength / 100);
            return yh;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by 100 is definitely wrong, it should be 256, not 100.

However you don't need to do all that.

```
private static byte getYLHeight(int height) {
    return (byte) height;
}

private static byte getYHHeight(int height) {
    return (byte) (height >>> 8);
}
```

To print the `byte` values in hex and decimal, use `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("YL: hex=%1$02x, decimal=%1$d%n", Byte.toUnsignedInt(hw.getYLHeight(400)));
System.out.printf("YH: hex=%1$02x, decimal=%1$d%n", Byte.toUnsignedInt(hw.getYHHeight(400)));
```

*Output*

```
YL: hex=90, decimal=144
YH: hex=01, decimal=1
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want the methods to return a `String` with the 2-digit hex representation of the `byte` value, do this instead:

```
private static String getYLHeight(int height) {
    return String.format("%02x", height & 0xFF);
}

private static String getYHHeight(int height) {
    return String.format("%02x", (height >>> 8) & 0xFF);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println("YL - " + hw.getYLHeight(400));
System.out.println("YH - " + hw.getYHHeight(400));
```

*Output*

```
YL - 90
YH - 01
```

Comment: Hi Andreas thank for that, can you please explain how these two work please %1$02x and %1$d%n

Comment: I donot want to print them, i just want the function to return 90 and 01

Comment: @BRDroid `90` and `01` are the hex representations of the values. You specifically wanted the return value to be a `byte`, not a `String`, so you get the numerical *value*, not the hex representation. --- As for `%1$02x` and `%1$d%n`, read the documentation on how the format string works: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax